# Cannot display IO [[String]] in app created in Spock and Lucid

Tags: haskell, io, haskell-spock, haskell-lucid

I have an issue with Spock, Lucid and IO in Haskell. I've got a function

```
f :: MySQLConn -> IO [[String]]
```

Output of `f` is result of statement "SELECT * FROM TABLE" with converted [MySQLValue] lists to [String] lists.

Then I want to use function `f` in Spock to display output in my app. I tried to use something like:

```
(...)
 get "history" $ lucid $ do 
        let offers = c >>= f
        mapM (mapM (p_ . toHtml) ) offers
(...)
```

Where `c` is used to create a connection with DB.
But it doesn't work. An error is: "No instance for (Traversable IO) arising from a use of ‘mapM’".

If I try:

```
 get "history" $ lucid $ do 
        mapM (mapM (p_ . toHtml) ) [["a", "b"], ["1","x"]]
```

it is correct. So my question is - how can I use the result of `f` in this app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can perform the IO action inbetween `get` and `lucid`:

```hs
 get "history" $ do
        offers <- liftIO $ c >>= f
        lucid $ mapM (mapM (p_ . toHtml) ) offers
```

With `liftIO` from [`Control.Monad.IO.Class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html#v:liftIO).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I tried it, but after lucid. Now I understand my mistake. :)